# HAproxy wont see Apache after uninstall Nginx, why?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, nginx, haproxy

I have a website I need to mount and I'm doing so with an HAproxy as load balancer, 3 webservers, 1 memcached, another HAproxy and a mysql galera cluster with 3 servers. All in CentOS 7.

Anyway I mounted the website with Nginx and the developers told me to do it with Apache, so I unistalled Nginx and put Apache. Now HAproxy wont see my webserver and is listing it as timeout in the monitor ui, and ofcourse I get timeout if I try to access the website.

Here's my HAproxy configuration:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2
    chroot  /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    # turn on stats unix socket
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    timeout connect 5000
    timeout client  50000
    timeout server  50000

frontend apache-webservers
    bind *:80
    mode http
    default_backend apache-nodes

backend apache-nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:www.mysite.com
    server web1 192.128.109.5:80 check
#   server web2 192.128.109.6:80 check
#   server web3 192.128.109.7:80 check

listen stats *:1935
    stats enable
    stats uri /

stats hide-version
stats auth monitor:mypassword
```

I installed **links** in my webserver and I can browse the site perfectly. The problem is through HAproxy. The funny thing is thet in my HAproxy server I can connect to the webserver using **telnet** perfectly.

In my webserver I have both firewalld and selinux disabled for now, so it's not an access problem.

What can be happening here? Why it worked while I have Nginx and not now with Apache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you check the HAproxy stats page, what is the status of the backend?

Comment: HAproxy says "level 7 timeout". Another curious thing is that with **links** installed in the HAproxy server I actually can browse the website.

Comment: Level 7 timeout means it can connect, it's just not getting an answer... There's usually a space between `Host:` and the hostname, add it to your `httpchk` line (i.e. `option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www.mysite.com`)